# SolrNet: How to use a custom searchcomponent (and its result) from solrnet

Tags: solrnet

On a project I'm working on we interact with Solr using SolrNet. We have a custom search component in solr, activated by adding `join=true` to the query. (I do this in solrnet through the `ExtraParams` of the `CommonQueryOptions`).
In the response there is a custom `<lst name="joinresult">` after the normal results which I want to parse, and return to the caller.

Now I don't know where I can cleanly insert a custom ResponseParser in the SolrNet pipeline.

What have I done so far:

- Created a `JoinResult<T>` class to hold my custom result
- Created a `JoinQueryResults<T> : SolrQueryResult<T>` with a `IList<JoinResult<T>> JoinResult` property.
- Created a `IJoinResponseParser<T> : ISolrResponseParser<T>` interface
- Created a `JoinResponseParser<T> : IJoinResponseParser<T>` to parse the custom list result into the `JoinQueryResults.JoinResult` property.

The next step was to plug all these classes in the right places, and use `SolrQueryExecuter<T>.Execute` to do the rest of the heavy lifting. But this will always return a SolrQueryResult, not my custom result.

Does anybody have any idea what I need to to support my scenario?

EDIT:
What I've got so far is the following:

- Derive from `SolrQueryExecuter<T>` and add a `ExecuteJoin(q,options)` method which returns a `JoinQueryResults<T>`.

This works, but it doesn't really feel 'right'. My Execute method is a copy of the normal Execute method with only one essential change: I replaced `new SolrQueryResults` with `new JoinQueryResults`.

Reading the SolrNet code I couldn't find any other 'easy' way, so I'm keeping this approach for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the SolrNet library supports inserting custom response parsers without modifying the source.

However, I would recommend checking out the source for [SolrNet on GitHub](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) and look at how the Faceting or Highlighting results are being parsed out of the SolrQueryResponse. Based on one of these examples you should be able to modify the source to handle the JoinQueryResults you have created. Then ideally, you could contribute this back to the project so that others may benefit as well.

Comment: Hi Paul, reading the code I think I'm stuck on the line `var results = new SolrQueryResults<T>();` in the `Execute` method of `SolrQueryExecuter`. I would have liked to be able to new my derived SolrQueryResults class.

Comment: I do not think that you want to create a derived JoinQueryResults. You should create a property on the SolrQueryResults<T> class that is of type JoinResults<T> and then have your JoinResponseParser<T> class populate that property in the SolrQueryResults. Again, I would look to mimic the functionality of the HighlightingResponseParser.

Comment: Adding a property to SolrQueryResults would work, but I would rather not build my own custom solrnet assembly from source. I really prefer to keep my SolrNet reference to be the standard one, and build my own behaviors on top of the binary distribution.

Comment: @rjvdboon no good way to do this ATM. see also http://groups.google.com/group/solrnet/browse_thread/thread/bd61f7bfd152ed55